# create var from .exe output in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to make a variable from the ID number of a username

```
qwinsta.exe /server:vm041 derpy.herp
```

This returns the following output

```
SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
                  derpy.herp                3  Disc
```

I need to create a variable in powershell with a value of 3 as per output above.

This code will be used to look through a number of servers to see if an individual user is logged in and disconnect them with rwinsta.exe

Comment: Can a user be logged on to the same machine more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's quite a crude regular expression - I don't know qwinsta.exe so I'm not sure of the permutations of data it can return - this works with your above example though.

This will assign 3 to the variable $ID.

```
$output = qwinsta.exe /server:vm041 derpy.herp
$output -match ".*derpy.herp.*(\d).*"
$ID = $Matches[1]
```

you may be able to parameterise the username like so:

```
$username = "derpy.herp"
$output = qwinsta.exe /server:vm041 $username
$output -match ".*$username.*(\d).*"
$ID = $Matches[1]
```

HTH,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the output you are obtaining, get your ID, and then use `New-Variable` cmdlet to instance your variable.